# JPanels and Playing music

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, audio, jpanel

I have a program that has multiple JPanels in a JFrame. At certain times, only one panels is visible [setVisible(true)] while all the others aren't [setVisible(false)]. What I would like is for a set piece of music to play while that JPanel is visible, but pause when it's not. I have a class that plays audio

```
public class AudioPlay extends Thread { 

private String filename;
private Position curPosition;

private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; // 128Kb 

enum Position { 
    LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
};

public AudioPlay(String wavfile) { 
    filename = wavfile;
    curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
} 

public AudioPlay(String wavfile, Position p) { 
    filename = wavfile;
    curPosition = p;
} 

public void run() { 
    while(true){
        File soundFile = new File(filename);
        if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
            System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + filename);
            return;
        } 

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try { 
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine auline = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try { 
            auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            auline.open(format);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                    .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
                pan.setValue(1.0f);
            else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
                pan.setValue(-1.0f);
        } 

        auline.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

        try { 
            while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                    auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally { 
            auline.drain();
            auline.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

So in each class extends a JPanel and has an AudioPlay as a parameter. When the JPanel is first created is calls the start() method. But then I've constantly got all the audio files playing.

**Can anyone show me a JPanel that will pause the start() method of one of these AudioPlay classes while that JPanel isn't visible?**

***EDIT***

Okay, so I had an idea and played around a bit, and now I can get it to play the audio only when its visible! It plays the previous panels music for a second or two after its visibility is turned off but for the most part is does what it should! For anyone who needs it here's the updated one.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl; 
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AudioPlay extends Thread { 

private String filename;
private Position curPosition;
JPanel panel;

private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; // 128Kb 

enum Position { 
    LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
};

public AudioPlay(String wavfile, JPanel panel) { 
    filename = wavfile;
    curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
    this.panel = panel;
} 

public AudioPlay(String wavfile, Position p, JPanel panel) { 
    filename = wavfile;
    curPosition = p;
    this.panel = panel;
} 

public void run() { 
    while(true){
        File soundFile = new File(filename);
        if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
            System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + filename);
            return;
        } 

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try { 
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine auline = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try { 
            auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            auline.open(format);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                    .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
                pan.setValue(1.0f);
            else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
                pan.setValue(-1.0f);
        } 

        auline.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
        try { 
            while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
                if(this.panel.isShowing()){
                    nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                    if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                        auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                }
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally { 
            auline.drain();
            auline.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ComponentListener` although it has never worked for me